# Reading a beans.xml file and storing it using JSON

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a project, where I need to read through a `bean.xml` file (`Spring` framework) and possibly store it in `JSON` or any other linked data types. The ultimate goal is to recreate the `bean.xml` file with some modification. I tried out `Dom4J` to process the `bean.xml` as a normal `XML` which failed with `class not found exception` and after digging deep it went on with no proper `node` definition. So I need advice on how to go on with this, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the `bean.xml`? Why not use the regular extends like `BeanPostProcessor` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`?

Comment: the `bean.xml` which i want to modify is used by another application. I don't really intend to modify any structure its just the arguments and parameters that i want to modify. Implementing each class for just modifying the parameter would suck up my time, which is why i thought a regular parser like `Dom4j` would be an easier way. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: Copy `bean.xml`, update and be done? Why should you use a parser for that? Also if those properties really differ between application those should be in a properties file so you can supply them at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is a namespace problem. Please see this url for reference [DOM4J Parse not returning any child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071331/dom4j-parse-not-returning-any-child-nodes)

If it is not a case, could you please provide your code?